# Remote connection on Windows virtual machine (Hyper-V)

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

So I have Ubuntu (17.04 I believe) running on a VM on Hyper-V, on my Windows 10.

Once I connect to it, through Hyper-V, I wanted to pin the "Virtual Machine Connection" application which opens itself thinking I could connect to it quicker later.

However once I close the connection (the VM is still running), I click on this app ("Virtual Machine Connection") to reconnect to it, and I get to a similar interface as the windows RDP. On this "similar interface (see screenshot)" there is a message printed saying i don't have the authorization to use this task.

Yet going through Hyper-V I can still connect to the VM...

My questions :

- How do I set this RDP connection to this VM from windows 10?
- Where can I find this authorization option?
- Is it even possible to set up a remote connection, or something to avoid to have to through Hyper-V and right click to the VM to log on it?

I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://ashwaniashwin.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/configure-remote-desktop-connection-to-hyper-v-virtual-machine/) to set it up, but it doesn't work.

I did already set an internal switch to my VM to get internet access.

[image: similar RDP interface screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to run "Virtual Machine Connection" (vmconnect.exe) with administritive rights. I usually have this pinned on my windows taskbar with shortcut that automatically "Run as Administrator"

[image]

The reason it works with Hyper-V Manager without it is because the Hyper-V Manager snap-in is almost always already executed with administritive rights.